# Query an attribute from Principal object

Tags: c#, active-directory

I want to make it possible to query all possible Active Directory attributes([List of all AD User attributes](http://www.kouti.com/tables/userattributes.htm)) for a User object in Active Directory.
At the moment I'm doing the following for the attribute e.g.: `lastLogon`:

(principal is a `Principal` object)

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = principal.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
if (directoryEntry.Properties.Contains("lastLogon"))
{
   return directoryEntry.Properties["lastLogon"].Value.ToString();
}
```

But this gives me `System.__ComObject` as value because `directoryEntry` is empty.

My question is: How can I get the `lastLogon` (or all other User attributes) attribute from a Principal object?

Comment: Do you have a username? or any other property? do you have a service account? your current code seems rather fragile - it will only properly succeed if you use Windows Auth and/or impersonate in the same domain and not serialize the principal

Comment: but I can query other attributes like cn, company, displayName, givenName. Only lastLogon returns System.__ComObject. Do you know any other way to query the AD for attributes??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an extension class which worked for lastLogon:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/565593/How-to-get-the-REAL-lastlogon-datetime-from-Active